# Posting URL to a Blog

Tags: discussion, blog, self-promotion

I wanted to know is, is it violate any rules if I wrote a blog post for a given question and post it as a answer for that question.

There might be many reasons that answer is more suited as a blog post, like answer can be too long, have strong links to previous set of posts, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 8):

The answer that you post should be able to stand alone if all outgoing links were to die.

So if you really wanted to write a blog post, put a self-contained summary in the answer and then link to the blog post.

---

Also be aware that any question needs a blog post as an answer may hint at being too broad.

Answer (score 7):

Answers should be self-contained. That is, everything the reader needs to know should be in the answer post. If the answer won't stand on its own without the link, it's not a good answer.

That said, it's okay to link to a resource for further information. Don't make it a habit, though, or you'll be flagged for spamming.